# How does base address register gets address?

Tags: linux, enumeration, pci, addressing, base-address

I've finished developing a pcie driver for an FPGA under a linux distributiuon. Everything works fine. But I'm wondering where the base address register in the PCI Endpoint of the FPGA gets the base address. When I've generated the PCIe Endpoint I was able to set up the length of the BAR, but not more.

In the PCIe driver I do the standard functions like pci_enable_device, but I do not set up specifically a base address.

So does the operating system set up the base address during startup? or how does it work?
By the side I would like to know what initialisations the operating system gernerally do if an pcie pcie device is connected. Since I do see my pci device in lspci even if the driver is unloaded.

Kind regards
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

The address allocation for the PCI devices are generally done at the BIOS level. Let us refer to the x86 platform. If we look closely at the system address map, it would be something like this (image taken from BIOS DISASSEMBLY NINJUTSU, by Darmawan Salihun)

[image]

On the address map, there is a dedicated space to map the PCI memory regions. The same could be replicated using the output of `/proc/iomem`.

This implementation is platform dependent, and as the BIOS "knows" about the platform, it would set aside the addresses dedicated to the PCI slots. When a device is plugged into the slot, the BIOS interacts with the firmware on the device and actually sets up the memory regions for the device, such that the OS could make use of it.

Now coming to the drivers part. In Linux, the drivers follow a specific standard known as the 'Linux Device Model', which constitutes a Core Layer(PCI core), Host Controller Drivers(PCI Controller/Masters) and Client Drivers(PCI devices). When the PCI device(client) is plugged into the slot, the corresponding host controller knows about the attachment and it further informs the PCI core about it, and hence appears in the output of `lspci`.

`lspci` shows the devices which are identified by the host controller, in which case, it may or may not be tied to a driver. The core further traverses the drivers in the system, finds a matching one, and attaches to this device.

So, the reason you are seeing the device in the output of `lspci` is because the host controller has identified the device, and has informed the PCI core. It doesn't matter even if any driver is attached to the device or not.

Answer (score 0):

On most consumer grade computers, BAR allocation seem to be done in the BIOS.

I suppose that in a hotplug capable architecture this must be done or at least triggered by the OS.